# QUERY function to grab columns from one tab and add column with a fixed cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am using `QUERY` function to grab first two columns from one sheet (say A) and want to add certain cell (Sheet B cell E1) value to next (3rd) column for non-empty imported rows. (if 5 rows are imported in column A and B, in column C, it should copy cell E1)

```
=QUERY(A!A:B, B!E1 )
```

> Error:
>   Formula parse error.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pTVfcoxM2wQTMC-3iLzXVXIEEaZFYXaOf97amy4yRg/edit#gid=1977458317

Answer (score 0):

from what I understood you want this:

```
={QUERY(A!A2:B, "select * where A is not null", 0),
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(E1&"♥", COUNTA(
  QUERY(A!A2:B, "select A where A is not null", 0))), "♥"))}
```

[image]